# Redirect to parent window from child window and close the child window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I am opening a website's(www.child.com) login page in new popup **window** from my website(www.parent.com).

Once the processing is done from **www.child.com** , it redirects to my **www.parent.com** website in child window.

But it should close the child window and should redirect to parent window.

Please provide some solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below :

```
window.opener.location.reload();
close();
```

1. window.opener.location.reload(); will reload the parent window.
2. close() will close the child window

It works fine for me.